# Two different terminal line commands - the same result

Tags: command-line, cat, less

What is the difference between

`less file-name`

and

`cat file-name | less`

For example:

`less .bashrc`

and

`cat .bashrc | less`

output the same result.

Comment: What you are describing is known as *Useless use of cat (UUoC)* - see for example  [Useless use of cat](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/useless-use-of-cat/) or [Useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: @steeldriver agreed. I think your UUoC links are the Answer.

Comment: Both instructions allow paging. However, as the above mentioned [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat) points out, the cat file-name | less approach is more readble.

Comment: `less filename` creates ONE process, `cat filename | less` creates TWO processes. UUoC, indeed!

Comment: @waltinator, _"A cat written with UUOC might still be preferred for readability reasons, as reading a piped stream left-to-right might be easier to conceptualize."_ says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two differences between `less file-name` and `cat file-name | less`:

1. `less file-name` creates one process, while `cat file-name | less` creates two processes.
2. `cat file-name | less` might be preferred for [readability reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat), as reading a piped stream left-to-right might be [easier to understand](http://www.compciv.org/topics/bash/pipes-and-redirection/).